# Container for relatively positioned children

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

Using WPF, I need something like `Canvas`, but with the option that elements are sized in relation to the canvas. I'm displaying an `Image` and multiple `Rectangle` elements and would like to have the image as well as the rectangles sized when the container is resized. Using a `Canvas`, the elements always retain the original size.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement for a `Canvas`? This could very easily be achieved using a `Grid`.

Comment: The rectangles use Grid.Top/Grid.Left for positioning within the parent. What would be the equivalent attributes when using a Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use a [`ViewBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) around your `Canvas`. Try this:

```
<ViewBox>
    <Canvas>
        <!-- Your elements -->
    </Canvas>
</ViewBox>
```

You should set the [`Stretch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`StretchDirection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.stretchdirection(v=vs.110).aspx) properties according to your needs. The `ViewBox` will scale all UI elements inside equally. Please see the first linked page on MSDN for further help with this class.

Comment: After setting an explicit width and height on the canvas, this works; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`ViewBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx). And yes, it's a short, but an answer =P.